# Criar campos dinamicamente e setar no model

Tags: c#, ajax, .net

Estou desenvolvendo um cadastro, onde tenho meus campos de acordo com o meu model:

```
public class Autor
{
    [Key]
    public int IdAutor { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}
```

ou seja, no meu arquivo `.cshtml` vai ter os `inputs` do `Model`.

Até ai tudo bem, agora, por exemplo, se eu quiser adicionar mais um `Autor` dinamicamente, sem sair da pagina, utilizando `AJAX`, de fato, fazer a chamada:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#addItem").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("AdicionarNovoAutor", "Autores")',
                success: function (html)
                {
                    $("#addnovo").append(html);
                },
                error: function (html)
                {
                    console.log("Erro");
                }
            });

        });        
});
```

Então, quando eu clicar no meu botão `#addItem` vou no meu `Controller` e retorno uma `PartialView` dos meus `inputs`, segue a `PartialView`:

```
@model List<MVC1.Models.Autor>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[0].Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[0].Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[0].DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[0].DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

esse código vai pra minha div, mas no meu `Controller` não consigo pegar os que eu adicionei, segue o `Controller` quando vou pro `Create`:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarNovoAutor(List<Autor> autores)
    {
        autores.Add(new Autor());

        return PartialView("~/Views/Autores/_AutorPartial.cshtml", autores);
    }
```

No caso, estou tentando passar como parâmetro uma lista dos Autores, não sei se ta certo. espero que entendam o meu problema, obrigado e aguardo a ajuda.

Comment: Deixo tentar entender. Você tem uma view e quer ir adicionando campos novos pelo html, e quando salvar, tem que ir todos esses campos? 1 - Se os campos forem todos previamente conhecidos, fica mais fácil. Voce nem precisa retornar partialview. Faz a criação dos novos campos via jquery mesmo. No seu POST, você manda a lista como ta fazendo.

Comment: @jpgrassi Bom dia, isso mesmo, eu to criando meus campos via `jQuery` só que la no controller ele nao consegue ler esses que eu criei. quando vc fala em meu POST, é no @Html.BeginForm ou  no POST do `AJAX`?

Comment: Então, acredito que isso que você está tentando fazer (passar o model no momento do retorno da partialview) não vá funcionar. Eu já implementei algo parecido mas eu utilizei angularJS. Eu ia adicionando os campos na tela normal via javascript e ia adicionando os "autores" em um array de objetos. Na hora que ia salvar, enviava um POST passando a lista dos autores pro meu controller.

Comment: Pesquisei um pouco, talvez isso ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148103/mvc-4-how-do-i-pass-model-data-to-a-partial-view

Comment: @jpgrassi Tentei aqui, mas não funcionou, tem skype? ou podemos falar no chat?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, temos vários erros... **DEBUGAR/DEPURAR o código é a melhor ferramenta para localizar erros**

1. Você está fazendo uma requisição GET (via AJAX) ao método **AdicionarNovoAutor**, este método espera uma lista de Autor como parâmetro, porem no seu código Javascript, que faz a requisição AJAX, você não está passando os que já foram criados de volta para o controle, se você debugar seu código, vai ver que o parâmetro **autores** está chegando `null` no controller. Mas isso nem é um problema, porque isso, como vou explicar a frente é inútil...
2. Não tem porque você mandar de volta para o controller a lista de autores já preenchidas pelo usuário, só para adicionar novos campos (autores), isso é uma tarefa de front-end não do back-end, a menos que você efetue algum processamento dos dados não faz sentido todo esse tráfego de dados.
3. Caso você realmente precise enviar de volta os dados só para adicionar mais um, altere a action para POST, mude o javascript para enviar os dados via POST e envie os dados de fato, via propriedade data do módulo AJAX do jQuery que você está utilizando
4. Sua partial view tem 4 problemas (vide itens 5, 6, 7 e 8 abaixo).
5. Você está renderizando os scripts a cada vez que você chama a partial view (a região "Scripts" no final), você só precisa deles 1x na sua página, o ideal é colocar essa chamada na _Layout ou na View completa mesma, não é isso que está fazendo seu código não funcionar como esperado, mas isso é um erro.
6. O model da sua partial view aponta uma lista de Autor `@model List<MVC1.Models.Autor>`, mas em nenhuma parte da sua partial view você está tratando ela como uma lista (não existe um for, nem um foreach ou um do/while), o que torna novamente inútil passar para o método **AdicionarNovoAutor** como foi falado no item 1.
7. Você está utilizando `@Html.BeginForm`na partial view, isso significa que cada vez que você chamar a partial view, um novo formulário será criado na página final, ao submeter os dados, apenas os dados de um formulário será enviado ao controller, como cada formulário só possui 1 autor, você vai perder os dados informados nos outros campos.
8. Você está criando os campos na partial view como se fosse um modelo simples, mas você quer uma matriz/lista de Autor, logo você precisa dizer ao HTML que cada campo da view pertence a uma matriz, adicionando colchetes no final do nome do campo `nomedocampo[]`

Vamos ao exemplo funcional:

**Javascript - funções para adicionar novos campos na tela e monitorar o clique no botão #addItem - novoAutor.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addItem").click(adicionaNovosCampos);
    adicionaNovosCampos(); //já chama a função para exibir os campos do primeiro autor
});

function adicionaNovosCampos(){
    var html = "Nome: <input type='text' name='Nome[]' /><br />Data de nascimento: <input type='date' name='DataNascimento[]' />";
    $("#formulario").append(html);
}
```

**HTML - a view principal, nada de partial view - NovoAutor.cshtml**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Salvar","Autor", FormMethod.Post)){
    <div id="formulario"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addItem">Adicionar novo autor</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
}
@section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     <script type="text/javascript" src="novoAutor.js"></script>
}
```

**Controller - com as actions de exibir a View(formulário) e o método para salvar os dados em um suposto banco de dados - Autor.cs**

```
public ActionResult NovoAutor() {
    return View();
}   

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Salvar(Autor[] autores) {
    var db = new DatabaseContext();
    foreach(var autor in autores)
        db.Autor.Add(autor);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Bom, isso acima é apenas um exemplo prático (não testado, escrito agora no Stack Overflow) de como seria para adicionar novos campos na tela de forma dinâmica sobre demanda e como salvar enviar os itens para o controle também.

Como você poderá perceber, é um exemplo bem básico, que não tem nenhuma "estilização" e nem validação dos dados, apenas fiz funcionar o que você estava com problemas, fica a seu cargo entender e modificar para ficar totalmente funcional a sua necessidade!

Obviamente isso deve servir de estudo para você aprimorar seu conhecimento, juntamente com isso, recomendo a leitura do seguinte artigo: [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)